# AWS VPC NAT | ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, nat, aws, subnets

I had a tough misleading error while connecting in AWS VPC subnets.
The error did occur in B->A connection, and did not happen while A->B, so at the beginning I thought that it is library bug.

It happened to be caused by AWS-system "double layer routing, and the NAT instance in the subnet, that did redirect packets over wrong network channel, causing ssh to drop connection.

Below there is a copy of mine post with 'case-study', that was deleted from the original thread:

> As far as I can tell this isn't even attempting to answer the question, so I'm deleting it. If you have a separate question feel free to post it as one |@michael-mrozek

In my case:

as @patrick suggested ([ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-pee)):

**CLIENT (subnetB 172.16.3.76)**

```
ssh 172.16.0.141 -vvv -p23
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.0.141 [172.16.0.141] port 23.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

**SERVER (SubnetA 172.16.0.141)**

```
$(which sshd) -d -p 23
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #2 type 3 ECDSA
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key': No such file or directory
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd' 
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='23'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 23 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 23.   
debug1: Bind to port 23 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 23.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
debug1: getpeername failed: Transport endpoint is not connected
debug1: get_remote_port failed
```

https://superuser.com/questions/856989/ssh-error-ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer

---

**The VPC setup and case description:**

I do have AWS EC2 Amazon instances running in the VPC (172.16.0.0/16)

- There is public subnetA (172.16.0.0/24), with NAT-instanceA (172.16.0.200) with attached elastic IP
- The other instances in subnetA  communicates to the internet via instanceA (default via 172.16.0.200 dev eth0)
- There are instances in subnetB (172.16.3.0/24)
- route table is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243833/how-to-connect-to-outside-world-from-amazon-vpc

#### The problem:

- The hosts both from subnetA and subnetB can ping/communicate.
- The hosts from subnetA can ssh to host in subnetB
- The hosts from subnetB can ssh to instanceA in subnetA
- NONE of the hosts in subnetB can ssh to OTHER instance in subnetA (other than instanceA), there is an error :
  ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
  IF_AND_ONLY_IF the instances in SubnetA HAVE defaut gateway set to NAT-InstanceA (example 'default via 172.16.0.200 dev eth0'). If there is instance_in_subnetA with not_changed default gateway (example 'default via 172.16.0.1 dev eth0'), then You can ssh to that instance from SubnetBhosts
- comment: If there won't be a NAT in subnetA, the instances in subnetA won't have outgoing internet connection

#### So...

The problem is probably caused by Amazon AWS Router and/or NAT configuration.

For the moment, I guess, that despite the fact, that the **VPC routing table** is set to:

```
Destination Target 
172.16.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0   igw-nnnnn
```

**The subnetA** instances are in

```
172.16.0.0/24
```

(**edit: source of the problem**: routing table redirecting traffic other than 172.16.0.0/24 via NAT instance, overriding AWS-side-Routing: 172.16.0.0/16)

```
default via 172.16.0.200 dev eth0 
172.16.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.0.60
```

**The subnetB** instances are in

```
172.16.3.0/24
```

When hosts from subnetB connect to instances in subnetA (other than NAT-instanceA), the traffic goes like:

```
172.16.3.X/24  --> 172.16.3.1 --> 172.16.0.Y  
                                      V
                        ???   <-- 172.16.3.200 (NAT)
```

And that is the problem. I would have to `tcpdump` that and verify, it might be fixable via NAT rules, though it is more complex than it should be.

Actually, the rule in AWS router

```
Destination Target 
172.16.0.0/16 local
```

should in theory cover the VPC/16 subnet, but the instance/24 subnet + NAT gateway hide the functionality on the "system_level".

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? I'm sorry but I can't see it if there is. The beginning looks like an answer, and then there's some problem statements in the middle - are those what you're trying to get resolved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the instances in subnetA (with NAT-instance 172.16.0.200), the routing table looks like:

```
default via 172.16.0.200 dev eth0
172.16.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.0.141
```

actually, the one addition:

```
$ ip r a 172.16.3.0/24 via 172.16.0.1
(or ip r a 172.16.3.0/16 via 172.16.0.1)
```

Fixes the system routing table:

```
default via 172.16.0.200 dev eth0
172.16.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.0.141
172.16.3.0/24 via 172.16.0.1 dev eth0
```

and shifts the VPC subnets routing over to AWS routers

```
Destination Target 
172.16.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0   igw-nnnnn
```